# JS .includes() with more than one values of array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers like  `A = ['1', '34', '23', '55']` and want to use .includes() to find true or false. However, my tested values are in array like `B = ['3', '1', '543', '33']`

I'd tried to do `A.includes(B)` but it seems it is not working. `A.includes('1', '123')` returns true. How can I use my Array B to do the same?

I wanted to Check if the array A has at least one of the array B’s value then return true. Apology for missing this part!

Comment: What sort of logic are you looking for? Every value of B needs to be in A? One value of B needs to be in A?

Comment: Returns true if one of the value of B is in the A. Sorry for lack of info :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want to check if `array` **B** all of it's element includes
in `array` **A** or not it would be like this using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
B.every((el) => A.includes(el))
```

```js
let A = [1, 2, 3], B = [2, 3, 4]
let result = B.every((el) => A.includes(el))
console.log(result)
```

and if you want at least one element from the second `array` to be in the first one you could do like this using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
B.some((el) => A.includes(el))
```

```js
let A = [1, 2, 3], B = [2, 3, 4];
let result = B.some((el) => A.includes(el))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to do `A.includes(B)`, but your inputs are stored in arrays. In this case, simply loop through the values and call `includes()` on the elements:

```js
const A = ['1', '34', '23', '55'];
const B = ['3', '1', '543', '33'];

for (var i = 0; i < A.length; ++i)
  console.log(A[i].includes(B[i]));
```

Answer (score 2):

`includes()` does not work this way. Per the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> arr.includes(valueToFind[, fromIndex])

Where `valueToFind` is a single value and `fromIndex` is the index to start looking from. (In your case it looks like it ignored that because it was a string; otherwise it would have returned `false`.)

If what you want is to find if array A contains every element of array B, there's no standard library function that does exactly that. Here's what you can do:

```
function containsAll(container, contained) {
  return contained.every(item => container.includes(item))
}

containsAll(A, B);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check if all values in `B` are in `A`, you can do it like below:

```js
B.every(item => A.includes(item)) // true or false
```